# 404 Page Not Found in 000webhost

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter

i created one registration and login page using codeIgniter it is working fine in localhost,i upload this file in 000webhost server that time it show error.help me to clear this issue.

i changed all the configuration correctly but it is not working

//htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

//index.php

```
<?php
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
case 'development':
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
break;

case 'testing':
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    }
    else
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
break;

default:
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
 }
 $system_path = 'system';
 $application_folder = 'application';
 $view_folder = '';
 if (defined('STDIN'))
 {
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
}

if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
{
    $system_path = $_temp.'/';
}
else
{
    // Ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';
}

// Is the system path correct?
if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
    echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}
 // The name of THIS file
 define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

// Path to the system folder
define('BASEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $system_path));

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');

// Name of the "system folder"
define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));

// The path to the "application" folder
if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $application_folder = $_temp;
    }

    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
else
{
    if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

// The path to the "views" folder
if ( ! is_dir($view_folder))
{
    if ( ! empty($view_folder) && is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.$view_folder;
    }
    elseif ( ! is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
    }
}

if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
{
    $view_folder = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
else
{
    $view_folder = rtrim($view_folder, '/\\').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}

define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder);
```

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

Comment: First off what version of codeigniter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a free account in 000webhost? if yes, there is a different .htaccess rules for subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to delete the default file in `htaccess` for you the access your uploaded file